# PDF File showing empty using retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm working on an app where I'm downloading a PDF file, saving it to internal storage and then opening that file in other app using FileProvider.

Note: It may be a duplicate question, I've gone through most of the questions on StackOverflow, but still didn't find the solution.

The file is getting downloaded fine but when I'm opening it, it is empty. 
The downlaoded file is 30 kb and it has 5 pages but all are empty. 
Initially, I thought it is empty because the other app doesn't have permission to open the file, but I did another thing to check whether it is a permission issue. I've saved the file to external storage, still, it was empty. So, it means it is not a permission issue.

**Please Note:**
Along with pdf file, there is some .xls file as well and when I'm opening those in excel android app, it says cannot open the file. This indicates, that there is some issue while writing the byte stream.

**Retrofit Interface.java**

```
@GET(ApiConstants.END_POINT_DOWNLOAD_DOCUMENT)
@Streaming
Call<ResponseBody> downloadDocument(@Query("bucket") String bucket, @Query("filename") String fileName);
```

**Code to Download the file:** Here I'm checking if a file is already there, then return the file, otherwise download the file.

```
public LiveData<Resource<File>> openOrDownloadFile(String bucket, String fileName) {
        MutableLiveData<Resource<File>> documentLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
        documentLiveData.postValue(Resource.loading(null));
        Context context = MyApp.getInstance();
        final File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), fileName);
        if (file.exists()) {
            documentLiveData.postValue(Resource.success(file));
        } else {
            Call<ResponseBody> call = apiService.downloadDocument(bucket, fileName);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        appExecutors.diskIO().execute(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                try {
                                    InputStream inputStream = null;
                                    OutputStream outputStream = null;
                                    try {
                                        byte[] fileReader = new byte[4096];
                                        inputStream = response.body().byteStream();
                                        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                                        while (true) {
                                            int read = inputStream.read(fileReader);
                                            if (read == -1) {
                                                break;
                                            }
                                            outputStream.write(fileReader, 0, read);
                                        }
                                        documentLiveData.postValue(Resource.success(file));
                                        outputStream.flush();
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        documentLiveData.postValue(Resource.error("Error: Unable to save file/n"+e.getLocalizedMessage(), null));
                                    } finally {
                                        if (inputStream != null) {
                                            inputStream.close();
                                        }

                                        if (outputStream != null) {
                                            outputStream.close();
                                        }
                                    }
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    Log.e(AppConstants.TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
                                    documentLiveData.postValue(Resource.error("Error: Unable to save file/n"+e.getLocalizedMessage(), null));
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        documentLiveData.postValue(Resource.error("Unable to download file", null));
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                    documentLiveData.postValue(Resource.error(t.getLocalizedMessage(), null));
                }
            });
        }

        return documentLiveData;
    }
```

Fragment Code

```
private void onItemClickListener(Document document) {
        mDocumentsViewModel.openORDownloadFile(document.getType(), document.getName()).observe(this, new Observer<Resource<File>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable Resource<File> fileResource) {
                binding.setResource(fileResource);
                if (fileResource.status == Status.SUCCESS) {
                    openFile(fileResource.data);
                }
            }
        });


    }

    void openFile(File file) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, file);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, mDocumentsViewModel.getMimeType(file.getAbsolutePath()));
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
        if (intent.resolveActivity(pm) != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "This file cannot be opened on this device. Please download some compatible app from play store", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

**Following are the versions :**
ext.retrofit_version = "2.4.0"
ext.okhttp_version = "3.8.0"

I'm struggling with this issue, it'll be a great help if you can point out the issue. Thank you.

**Update:** The problem was with the backend APIs. My code was correct. Once they've fixed the problem at there side, it started working at my side without any changes.

Comment: `The file is getting downloaded fine `. Really? And empty means filesize==0 ? Did you check?

Comment: `Here I'm checking if file is already there, then return the file, otherwise download the file.`. But if filesize is 0. Then what should you do!?

Comment: @greenapps I've checked the file size and it is 30kb. It has 5 pages, but all are empty.

Comment: And what is the size of the original file? In bytes please. Both file sizes in bytes. Not KB.

Comment: @greenapps. Thank you. I've the original file and its size is 21,177 bytes and the downloaded file size is 31056 bytes. I'm not sure how the difference is there. But I've checked one thing that both the files 5 pages.

Comment: The suzes should be equal. So you are downloading wrong.

Comment: Did you find the solution finally ? Was it due to Retrofit/OkHttp versions, like in the following ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38439201/how-to-download-a-pdf-file-with-retrofit-2 ?

Comment: @E.Bavoux, Yeah, this issue has been solved. I've updated my question.

Comment: What was the backend problem? I'm facing the same issue and am going pretty crazy...